# MySQL subquery count with calendar table slow

Tags: mysql, performance, count, innodb

I have a sales table in MySQL (InnoDB). It's +- 1 million records big. I would like to show some nice charts. Fetching the right data is not a problem. Fetching it fast is...

So I like to count the amount of sales in table A grouped per day (later on also month, and year) for PERIOD A till Z. Concrete; for the last 30 days I like to know for each day how many sales records we have in the DB.

So MySQL would have to return something like this:

I like to achieve that MySQL returns the data like this:

```
date, count
2017-04-01, 2482
2017-04-02, 1934
2017-04-03, 2701
...
```

The structure of the Sales basically like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `sales` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `contacts_created_at_index` (`created_at`),
  KEY `contacts_deleted_at_index` (`deleted_at`),
  KEY `ind_created_at_deleted_at` (`created_at`,`deleted_at`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Some days (datapoints) might not have any results, but I don't like to have gaps in the data. So I also have some 'calendar' table.

```
CREATE TABLE `time_dimension` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `db_date` date NOT NULL,
  `year` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `month` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `day` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `td_ymd_idx` (`year`,`month`,`day`),
  UNIQUE KEY `td_dbdate_idx` (`db_date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Fetching 30 rows (30 days) with a count per day takes 30 secs...

This is the first query I tried:

```
SELECT 
    `db_date` AS `date`,
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(1)
        FROM
            sales
        WHERE
            DATE(created_at) = db_date) AS count
FROM
    `time_dimension`
WHERE
    `db_date` >= '2017-04-11'
        AND `db_date` <= '2017-04-25'
ORDER BY `db_date` ASC
```

But like I said it's really slow (11.9 secs). I tried al kinds of other approaches, but without luck. For example:

```
SELECT time_dimension.db_date AS DATE,
       COUNT(1) AS count
FROM sales RIGHT JOIN time_dimension ON (DATE(sales.created_at) =         
    time_dimension.db_date)
WHERE
    (time_dimension.db_date BETWEEN '2017-03-11' AND '2017-04-11')
GROUP BY
    DATE
```

A query for just 1 datapoint takes only 5.4ms:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM sales WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2017-04-11 00:00:00' AND '2017-04-25 23:59:59'
```

I haven't checked innodb_buffer_poolsize on my local machine. I will check that as well. Any ideas on how to make queries like this fast? In the future I would even need to where clauses and joins, to filter the set of sales records..

Thanks.

Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to count sale data first, then join count result with your *calendar* table.

```
SELECT time_dimension.db_date AS date, 
       by_date.sale_count 
FROM   time_dimension 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT DATE(sales.created_at) sale_date, 
                         COUNT(1)               AS sale_count 
                  FROM   sales 
                  WHERE  created_at BETWEEN '2017-03-11 00:00:00' AND 
                                            '2017-04-11  23:59:59' 
                  GROUP  BY DATE(sales.created_at)) by_date 
              ON time_dimension.db_date = by_date.sale_date 
WHERE  time_dimension.db_date BETWEEN '2017-03-11' AND '2017-04-11'
```

Comment: That one seemed to work pretty fast! 3 months of data points (+-90) in 0.393 secs. Awesome. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The problematic part of your query is the data type conversion `DATE(created_at)`, which effectively prevents Mysql from using the index at `created_at`.

Your `1 datapoint` query avoids that, and that is why it is working fast.

To fix this you should check if `created_at` is within a range of specific day, like that:

```
created_at BETWEEN db_date AND DATE_ADD(db_date,INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

This way Mysql will be able to make use of index on it (do a range lookup), as appropriate.

Comment: I tried this one as well, but without luck. Even seemed to take a bit longer.

Comment: @nicktc - please show the full query you have tried (EXPLAIN plan would be nice  to see too)

Answer (score 0):

```
 WHERE DATE(created_at) = db_date)
```

-->

```
 WHERE created_at >= db_date
   AND created_at  < db_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

- This avoids including midnight of second day (as `BETWEEN` does)
- Work for all flavors: `DATE`, `DATETIME`, `DATETIME(6)`
- Does not hid the `created_at` inside a function where the index cannot see it.

For `time_dimension`, get rid of `PRIMARY KEY (id)` and change `UNIQUE(db_date)` to the PK.

After making these changes, your original subquery may be competitive with the `LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ... )`.  (It depends on which version of MySQL.)